# Как в vs Code выйти со скобки в конец строки комбинацией клавиш?

Tags: visual-studio-code

например var number = "word|"
или var arr = [2,3|]
Какой комбинацией клавиш выйти в конец строки(где стоит | это курсор) стрелка и end не выход

Comment: что показывает `|` - это где стоит курсор до или куда он должен попасть после нажатия?

Comment: где стоит курсор

Comment: тогда почему не подходит `end`?

Comment: клавиатуры разные на ноуте и компе и расположение, а при слепой печати не удобно каждый раз смотреть

Comment: Тогда можно включить поддержку вима и использовать символ `$` (на большинстве клавиатур это shift+4).

Comment: ну вим это уже слишком) в настройках должно по любому где то быть

Comment: В настройках конечно есть, но переиначивать это действие на отдельную комбинацию - плохо. Пойдете к соседу - и все... приплыли.

Comment: скачать extension tabOut - plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Горячие клавиши настраиваются. <kbd>File</kbd> - <kbd>Preferences</kbd> - <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За [переход к концу строки](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing) отвечает `id` - `cursorEnd`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

значение горячих клавиш для которого можно поменять на удобные.

Comment: я думал об этом способе, но думаю, что ему это не подойдет. Это же нужно будет на каждой машине себе настраивать. А если к соседу пришел?

Comment: @KoVadim, можно файл настроек с собой таскать :-)

Comment: если ко мне пришли и переиначили мои настройки, я бы рассказал, все что думаю. Поэтому, я нигде не переиначиваю кнопки.

Comment: @KoVadim, не, там ж просто файлик json, он вроде на уровне папки может работать

Comment: Это не имеет никакого значения. Я несколько раз встречал ситуацию, когда ко мне приходит человек и говорит, как то у тебя плохо клавиши настроены и давай перестраивать под себя. И тут же получает по рукам мышкой (беспроводной так не сделаешь).

Comment: @KoVadim, мне кажется тут немного другой случай :-)

Answer (score 0):

за скобку выскакивает просто Tab

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]